# Render multiple outputs from one Rmd

Tags: r-markdown

This is allegedly possible, but when I use the code example from the [RMarkdown Book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-html.html), I get only one output, whichever output is listed first.

`````
---
title: Render a table in a tiny environment
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

````{r, setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
options(knitr.table.format = function() {
  if (knitr::is_latex_output()) 'latex' else 'pandoc'
})
````
`````

I am using the most up-to-date versions of RStudio 2022.07.1 & knitr=1.39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Option 1**

you can use `rmarkdown::render` in `knit` yaml key and specify `ouput_format = "all"` to render the documents to all the specified formats in the yaml section.

````
---
title: Render a table in a tiny environment
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding,
  output_dir = "output", output_format = "all") })
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting 
syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. 
For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

After clicking on **Knit**, you will have both pdf and html file in the output folder.

### **Option 2**

Which is actually the same thing as option 1, but uses a bit different workflow.

In your Rmd file yaml section, you simply specify the output format like this,

````
---
title: Render a table in a tiny environment
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting 
syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. 
For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

Then in the console or another r-script, run this,

```r
rmarkdown::render('multiple_output.Rmd',output_dir = "output", output_format = 'all')
```

Again, similarly you will have both pdf and html file in the output folder.